# How to retrieve delivery table all data from product table and item table in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

//here is deliveries table

```
Schema::create('deliveries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('qty');
            $table->string('person_name');
            $table->string('designation');
            $table->string('Office');
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

// here is products table

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('item_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('brand_id');
            $table->string('item_model')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('qty');
            $table->unsignedInteger('item_price');
            $table->unsignedInteger('total_price');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

// here are items table

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('item_name')->unique();;
});
```

how to retrieve products and items table data from deliveries table by eloquent model?
I have 3 model files are Delivery.php, Item.php and Product.php
I want to access DeliveryController.php by index method. But I can't access item_name

```
public function index()
{
    return Delivery::with('user')
                    ->with('product')
                    ->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
}

<tr role="row" class="odd" v-for="(delivery, index) in deliveries" :key="index">
                        <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ delivery.product.item_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should add foreign key constraints on tables. Like This

```
Schema::create('deliveries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('qty');
            $table->string('person_name');
            $table->string('designation');
            $table->string('Office');
            $table->string('mobile');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');

            $table->foreign('product_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('products')
});
```

And to all tables like so. 
After that and assuming you have properly defined relationships on **Delivery** Model You Can do like This:

```
public function index()
{
    return Delivery::with(['user','product'])
                    ->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
}
```

Comment: actually bro, I have done this thing before. I can't fetch product and user table but I can't fetch item_name from items table. How can I fetch item_name from items table using Delivery model

Comment: Can you show **Delivery** Model and also tell how items are related to **Delivery** or **Product** model?

Comment: here is my file: https://github.com/ruhulrahman/Inventory/blob/master/app/Delivery.php

Comment: @RuhulAmin I think you have wrong table structure, there is no reference to items from delivery table. If you want to get items from delivery model you should define relationships between this models, or get them by nested eager loading. I suggest you to read [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationship) which will help you 100%

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to define this relationship on Delivery Model, please add this relationship on Delivery Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

after add, you can access `user` and `product` when you load delivery resources

```
Delivery::with(['user','product'])->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: actually bro, I have done this thing before. I can't fetch product and user table but I can't fetch item_name from items table. How can I fetch item_name from items table using Delivery model

Comment: yes you can fetch item name from item table if you make a relationship between product and item then just call {{ delivery.product.item.item_name}}